# Microstream data is not persisted when application restart using micronaut 3.9.4

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-rest, microstream

I have a below project structure

[image]

**API**

```
microstream:
  rest:
    enabled: true
  storage:
    order:
      root-class: 'fete.bird.entity.RootContainer'
      storage-directory: 'api/build/order-storage'
```

**Infrastructure**

```
@Singleton
public class OrderRepository implements IOrderRepository {
    private final RootProvider<RootContainer> rootProvider;

    public OrderRepository(RootProvider<RootContainer> rootProvider) {
        this.rootProvider = rootProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Order create(Order order) {
        Map<UUID, Order> root = rootProvider.root().getOrders();
        root.put(order.id(), order);
        return order;
    }
}
```

**Core**

```
@Introspected
public interface IOrderRepository {
    Order create(Order order);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller("/order")
public class OrderController {
private final IOrderRepository iOrderRepository;

    public OrderController(IOrderRepository iOrderRepository) {
        this.iOrderRepository = iOrderRepository;
    }

    @Post
    public Order post(Order model) {
        var result =iOrderRepository.create(model);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The data is not persisted when I stop the application and rerun it again, an empty map is loaded, it is not persisting the old data. A sample application https://github.com/anandjaisy/microstream-micronaut-issue

Comment: is this a gradle project? I see you store the data under api/build. Is maybe the restart clearing your build folder?

Comment: @saw303  yes it is a gradle project, even putting outside of build folder it is not persistent the data

Comment: IMHO the Gradle multi module project isn't set up properly. Only the `api` module is using the Micronaut Gradle plugin. All other modules are not preprocessed by Micronaut. That's probably why it work.

Comment: Since I think this issue is happening to your Gradle multi module configuration, I was wondering whether you have tried to implement it with a vanilla single module Micronaut application? For such a small application this module layering is a bit over engineered

Comment: @saw303 for single module Micronaut application it is working fine, not able to find the exact issue why it is not working for multi-module.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues that I found in your example project.

**API Module**

***Controller***

Unrelated to your question but I recommend to use `@Body` in your controller method, in order to tell Micronaut how to map the request payload.

```java
@Post
public Order post(@Body Order model) {
   var result = iOrderRepository.create(model);
   return result;
}
```

***Order record***

Convert your Java record to a POJO since Microstream has issues with records (see https://docs.microstream.one/manual/storage/faq/java-features.html)

```java
@Serdeable
public final class Order {
    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final String productId;

    public Order(UUID id, String name, String description, String productId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
}
```

**Infrastructure Module**

That module is not configured properly. No Micronaut compile-time processors are registered since you are not using the Micronauts Gradle plugin in that module. The `OrderRepository` is using the `StoreParams` annotation. This has only an effect when Micronaut preprocesses your code at compile time and generates additional code.

```java
@StoreParams("orders")
protected Order createOrder(Map<UUID, Order> orders, Order order) {
        orders.put(order.id(), order);
        return order;
}
```

Therefore you need to extend the `build.gradle` by registering the Micronaut `io.micronaut.library` plugin.

```
plugins {
    id("io.micronaut.library") version "3.7.10"
}

// ... other code omitted

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("fete.bird.*")
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

In your `application.yml` you are defining the storage `order` but in the repository implementation you are referring to `orders`.

```yaml
microstream:
  rest:
    enabled: true
  storage:
    order: # call this orders
      root-class: 'fete.bird.entity.RootContainer'
      storage-directory: 'api/build/order-storage'
```

```java
@Override
@StoreParams("orders")
public Order create(Order order) {
  rootProvider.root().getOrders().put(order.id(), order);
  return order;
}
```